# Could not connect to "Apple TV"

Tags: macbook-pro, appletv

I have recently updated both my Mac & Apple TV software now my Airplay mirroring is no longer working (though does through iTunes) I just receive a message saying Could not connect to "Apple TV" when clicking on the Airplay icon. It's not a WiFi issue as I can still access my computer via apple TV.

Comment: Using password or screen code or what ever it was named? I have problems with audio in airplay, I think problem is current AppleTV software, because earlier it  worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found it was because I had checked "Block all incoming connections" in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall > Firewall Options.